# Fijar elementos report viewer

Tags: .net, reportviewer, rdlc

tengo un problema con el rdlc que estoy haciendo en .NET, tengo una tabla que se va llenando dependiendo de los impuestos que los clientes deben abonar, esta tabla es dinámica, ya que diferentes clientes abonan diferentes impuestos. El problema es que esa tabla, al ir creciendo, empuja los textbox que coloque al final de la pagina. Ya los puse en rectángulos como indica en la documentación y en otros posts que fui viendo, pero no funciona, me los sigue empujando. Alguien le ah pasado para que me pueda dar una mano?

Answer (score 1):

ya encontré la solución, lo que hice fue colocar dentro de un rectángulo, un text box, y le defini la propiedad CanGrow a False, y dentro de este puse las tablas, ahora nada se mueve de su lugar. Espero le ayude a alguien mas esta solución. Saludos!!!!

Comment: hola gals tengo el mismo inconveniente unos textbox se me desplazan si cunado crece la tablix probe hacer lo que dices pero sigo igual las tanto los textbox como la tablix los agregue a un rectangulo